# How to append successful AJAX response to Drop down values in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to Select Department first from a drop down and then need to load officers in that particular department in another drop down list. I am doing this in Codeigniter.

**View** 
(Second Drop down where I have to load the Oficers Names. I have already loaded values for Department drop down, and upon department selection this dropdown should get select values)

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select name="Officer_InCharge" id="Officer_InCharge" class="form-control input-lg">
      <!--<option value="">Select officer</option>-->
   </select>
</div>
```

**My AJAX**

```
<script>
  $(document).change(function(){
    $("#Officer_Dept").click(function(){
      var Dept = $('#Officer_Dept').val();
      if (Dept != '') 
      {
        $.ajax({
          url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Crud/fetch_officers",
          method:"POST",
          data:{Dept:Dept},
          //dataType: 'json',
          success:function(data)
          {

            alert(data);

            var options = "";
             for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 options += "<option>" + data[i].user_name + "</option>";
             }
             $("#Officer_InCharge").html(options);
          }
        })
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

The AJAX call is successful, the problem I face is that with appending the ajax response to Officer selecting Drop Down. Those values display in alert

```
alert(data);
```

[image]
But Not being displayed in the drop down.

**My Controller**

```
public function fetch_officers()
    {
        if ($this->input->post('Dept')) 
        {
            echo $this->Crud_model->fetch_dept_officers($this->input->post('Dept'));

        }
    }
```

**My Model**

```
function fetch_dept_officers($Dept)
    {
        $this->db->where('user_dept',$Dept);
        $this->db->order_by('user_name', 'ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');

        $output = '<option value="">Select Officer</option>';
          foreach($query->result() as $row)
          {
            $output .= '<option value="'.$row->user_id.'">'.$row->user_name.'</option>';
            //$output += "<option value='"+$row->user_id+"'>"+$row->user_name+"</option>";
            //$output .= '<option>'.$row->user_name.'</option>';
            //formoption += "<option value='"+val+"'>"+val+"</option>";

            //
            //
          }
          return $output;
          //return $query->result();
    }
```

Appreciate if anyone can sort this out. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please tell me that if you return options from ajax call then why you are writing loop to create  options?

Comment: check your ajax response data. i think your data  in the form of string type.change string to object.

Comment: Remove the alert(data) and check if the for loop is executed.

Comment: I did tried with 
$('Officer_InCharge').html(data);
BUt still it didnt work @Madhuri PAtel

Comment: Undefined options are displaying in dropdown values...

Answer (score 1):

In ajax, you just have to add html into select box. For this you have to put below code in ajax.

```
<script>
  $(document).change(function(){
    $("#Officer_Dept").click(function(){
      var Dept = $(this).val();
      if (Dept != '') 
      {
        $.ajax({
          url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Crud/fetch_officers",
          method:"POST",
          data:{Dept:Dept},
          //dataType: 'json',
          success:function(data)
          {

            $("#Officer_InCharge").html(data);
          }
        })
      }else{
         alert('Please select Department');
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

In controller, you have to put below conditions

```
public function fetch_officers()
    {
        if ($this->input->post('Dept')) 
        {
            echo $this->Crud_model->fetch_dept_officers($this->input->post('Dept'));

        }else{
            echo "<option>No Officer Available.</option>";
        }

    }
```

In model:

```
function fetch_dept_officers($Dept)
    {
        $this->db->where('user_dept',$Dept);
        $this->db->order_by('user_name', 'ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');
        $optionsResult=$query->result();

    if(count($optionsResult)>0){
    $output = '<option value="">Select Officer</option>';

      foreach($optionsResult as $row)
      {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row->user_id.'">'.$row->user_name.'</option>';
        //$output += "<option value='"+$row->user_id+"'>"+$row->user_name+"</option>";
        //$output .= '<option>'.$row->user_name.'</option>';
        //formoption += "<option value='"+val+"'>"+val+"</option>";

        //
        //
      }
    }else{
     $output="<option>No Officer available</option>";
    }
      return $output;
      //return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just send array data via model :

```
function fetch_dept_officers($Dept)
    {
        $this->db->where('user_dept',$Dept);
        $this->db->order_by('user_name', 'ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users')->result_array();

        return $query ;

    }
```

First of all you need to send json encode data from controller to ajax.So make some changes in controller as follows :

```
public function fetch_officers()
{
   if ($this->input->post('Dept')) 
   {
     $result_data=$this->Crud_model->fetch_dept_officers($this->input->post('Dept'));
     echo json_encode($result_data); //send encoded data
    }
 }
```

in ajax you need to first parse that json and set data in html with the help of jquery.
please find the ajax code below:

```
$.ajax({
   url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Crud/fetch_officers",
   method:"POST",
   data:{Dept:Dept},
   success:function(data) {
      var parse_data = JSON.parse(data); //parse encoded data
      $.each(parse_data,function(index,value){
         $("#Officer_InCharge").append("<option>" + value.user_name + "</option>");   
      });
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#Officer_Dept').change(function () {
    var Dept = $('#Officer_Dept').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: base_url + '/Crud/fetch_officers',
        data: {
            Dept:Dept
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(data.data, function (i, value) {
                html += ('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.user_name + '</option>');

            });
            $("#Officer_InCharge").html(html);
        }
    });
});

//in controller

   function getInchargeOfficer(Request $request) {
        $inchargeOfficerArray = ModelName::where('dept', $request->Dept)->get();
        if (!empty($inchargeOfficerArray)) {
            return response()->json(['data' => $inchargeOfficerArray]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take a div or whatever in which you want to append your data. Id in your case is  Officer_InCharge,

```
$("#Officer_InCharge").append(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass only result array of query from your model to controller and from controller you can return the fetch_dept_officers result and in AJAX success call you can append option

**MY Model**

```
  function fetch_dept_officers($Dept)
        {
            $this->db->where('user_dept',$Dept);
            $this->db->order_by('user_name', 'ASC');
            $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');

            return $query->result();
        }
```